# If $A$ is a compact operator, then the rank of $A^*A$ is equal to the rank of $A$.

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators, adjoint-operators

Let $A$ be a compact operator on a Hilbert space and $r(A)$ be the rank of $A$, that is, the dimension of the image of $A$.

The inequality $r(A^*A)\le r(A^*)=r(A)$ is rather straightforward, but how do I get the other direction?

Comment: You could have gone directly with $r(A^*A)\le r(A)$, because $r(AB)$ is the dimension of the image of the map $\left.A\right\rvert_{\operatorname{im} B}:\operatorname{im} B\to V$, and thus $r(AB)\le \dim\operatorname{im} B=r(B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\langle x,A^\ast Ax\rangle=\langle Ax,Ax\rangle
$$
Thus, if $Ax\ne0$, then $A^\ast Ax\ne0$. This implies that $r(A^\ast A)\ge r(A)$.

Comment: Are there any issues when $H$ is infinite-dimensional?

Comment: @eloiPrime: good point. If we use the contrapositive, we get the statement without rank-nullity.

Comment: In the finite dimensional case every operator is compact. The question makes sense  in infinite dimensional case only if we interpret compact operators as finite rank operators.

Comment: I had assumed, since we were comparing $r(A)$, that we were considering finite rank operators. If they were both infinite rank, I would also consider their ranks equal.